# Where to set Project Path in Sonar?

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I am trying to set up Sonar with Maven Project. I haven't set path of the project anywhere. Please tell in  which file I have to set the path?

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO]

[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1

[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 0.188 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-18T11:27:53+05:30

[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M

[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look on the documentation? http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven